# How to change the button from upload to download button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to change the upload button to download button after the file has been uploaded without refreshing the page. Any idea to do this? My intial thought is using the ajax. but i do not know how the coding look like. I am kinda of new with this javacript and also ajax.Please help guys.Thank in advance

code that i use

```
<script>
$(function($){
    // File upload via Ajax
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        $(".progress-bar").width(percentComplete + '%');
                        $(".progress-bar").html(percentComplete+'%');
                        
                    //     $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#28A74B;">File has uploaded successfully!</p>');
                    // console.log('it works');
                    }
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function(){
                $(".progress-bar").width('0%');
            },
            error:function(){
                $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#EA4335;">File upload failed, please try again.</p>');
            },
            success: function(resp){
                // alert(resp == 'ok');
                // $('#uploadForm')[0].reset();
                // $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#28A74B;">File has uploaded successfully!</p>');
                if(resp == 'ok'){
                    $('#uploadForm')[0].reset();
                    $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#28A74B;">File has uploaded successfully!</p>');
                    
                }else if(resp == 'err'){
                    $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#EA4335;">Please select a valid file to upload.</p>');
                }
            }
        });
    });
    
    // File type validation
    $("#fileInput").change(function(){
        var allowedTypes = ['video/avi'];
        var file = this.files[0];
        var fileType = file.type;
        if(!allowedTypes.includes(fileType)){
            $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#EA4335;">Please select a valid file to upload.</p>');
            $("#fileInput").val('');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

html code use for the button

```
<?php 
    if (file_exists("D:/Files".$row['path'].".avi"))
   {
   ?>
   <form action="code4.php?file_id=D:/Files<?php echo $row['path']?>.avi" method="post">
   <button type="submit" name="download_btn" class="btn btn-success" id=download_btn> Download </button>
   </form>
   <?php
   }
   else
   {
   ?>
   <button type="button" data-fid='<?php echo $row['path']?>' name="upload_btn"class="btn btn-info upload_btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#uploadfile">Upload</button>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Where are the buttons? Please share html

Comment: done share the code

Answer (score 1):

Simply have two buttons, show only one at the time

```js
(function () {
  $(document).on('submit', '#main_form', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    /**
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      method: "",
      data: "",
      success: onSuccess
    })
    **/
    
    //function onSuccess() {
      $(this).addClass('uploaded');
    //}
  });
})();
```

```css
#download_btn {
  display: none;
}

.uploaded #download_btn {
  display: inline;
}

.uploaded #upload_btn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="main_form">
  <button type="submit" name="download_btn" class="btn btn-success" id="download_btn"> Download </button>
  <button type="submit" name="upload_btn" class="btn btn-success" id="upload_btn"> Upload </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're already checking if the file has been uploaded so add your code there:

```
if(resp == 'ok'){
  // Existing code:
  $('#uploadForm')[0].reset();
  $('#uploadStatus').html('<p style="color:#28A74B;">File has uploaded successfully!</p>');

  // New code: change "Upload" button to "Download:
  $('button[name="upload_btn"]').html('Download');
}
```

If you're trying to replace the entire Upload button with the HTML for the Download button:

```
$('button[name="upload_btn"]').replaceWith(
   '<button type="submit" name="download_btn" class="btn btn-success" id=download_btn> Download </button>'
);
```

Comment: Ty for your response.I use the second code and it works.However,when i click the button i cannot download the uploaded files back.

Comment: Another thing sir,what if i want to change only at one row since i have a lot of row in the table and all have upload button

Comment: @newbiedeveloper Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65822545/edit) to show an example of the HTML for several rows. Please show the final HTML output, not the PHP code.